# Mysql command to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

so basically I am trying to write a php script that can be uploaded to a server and be located somewhere on my site to click. Then when it's clicked, it runs the mysql query and displays the information needed....This is what I have so far.

--Connect.php--

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = '******';
$dbpass = '******';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die
        ('Error connecting to mysql');

$dbname = '*****';
mysql_select_db($dbname);

?>
```

--the mysql command I need to have the php file run is

```
SELECT jsfdName.baseData AS Name, 
jsfdAddr.baseData as Address, 
jsfdZip.baseData AS Zip,      
jsfdCity.baseData AS City, 
sfdCounty.baseData AS County, 
jsfdState.baseData AS State
FROM jos_sobipro_field_data AS jsfdName
JOIN jos_sobipro_field_data AS jsfdAddr USING( sid )
JOIN jos_sobipro_field_data AS jsfdZip USING(sid)
JOIN jos_sobipro_field_data AS jsfdCity USING(sid)
JOIN jos_sobipro_field_data AS jfsdCounty USING(sid)
JOIN jos_sobipro_field_data AS jfsdState USING(sid)
WHERE jsfdName.fid = 36 AND jsfdAddr.fid = 37 AND jsfdZip.fid=38 AND jsfdCity.fid = 39 
AND jsfdCounty.fid = 40 AND jsfdState.fid = 41 AND sid > 329
```

So how do I write the php script to run this file within my website?

Thanks

Comment: Are those values constant in your `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 1):

Store your query in a php variable `$query='That String'`

Then use this to execute it:

```
$res=mysql_query($qry);
```

Then to look through every result:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    print $row['Name']; }
```

:)

Comment: Can I do this inside of the connect.php file or should I make another file that just includes connect and then does this command?

Comment: You could include the "connect" stuff in a file and include it anywhere you'll be needing MySQL, however, you should try to only use mysql_connect and mysql_select_db one time per page. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this..

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = '******';
$dbpass = '******';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die
    ('Error connecting to mysql');

$dbname = '*****';
mysql_select_db($dbname);

$sql = "SELECT jsfdName.baseData AS Name, 
jsfdAddr.baseData as Address, 
jsfdZip.baseData AS Zip,      
jsfdCity.baseData AS City, 
sfdCounty.baseData AS County, 
jsfdState.baseData AS State
FROM jos_sobipro_field_data AS jsfdName
JOIN jos_sobipro_field_data AS jsfdAddr USING( sid )
JOIN jos_sobipro_field_data AS jsfdZip USING(sid)
JOIN jos_sobipro_field_data AS jsfdCity USING(sid)
JOIN jos_sobipro_field_data AS jfsdCounty USING(sid)
JOIN jos_sobipro_field_data AS jfsdState USING(sid)
WHERE jsfdName.fid = 36 AND jsfdAddr.fid = 37 AND jsfdZip.fid=38 AND jsfdCity.fid = 39 
AND jsfdCounty.fid = 40 AND jsfdState.fid = 41 AND sid > 329
";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {

echo "An error occurred in processing your    submission."; 
}   
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```